# How to find, filter and copy directory and contents to a location dictated by part of find result ) in Powershell

Tags: file, powershell, directory, copy

Using Powershell preferably, otherwise vbscript. perl or batch. (any way so it's not a manual job).

I have a list of user profiles:

```
\\fileserver\profiles\user1\findmedirectory\dir1
\\fileserver\profiles\user2\findmedirectory\dir1
\\fileserver\profiles\user3\notfindme\dir1
```

I wish to copy all instances of "findmedirectory" recursively down to

```
\\fileserver\newprofilesdirectory\user1\
\\fileserver\newprofilesdirectory\user2\
\\fileserver\newprofilesdirectory\user3\
```

by finding for example the first entry:

```
\\fileserver\profiles\user1\appdata\findmedirectory\dir1
`$dest = \\fileserver\newprofiledirectory
$user = user1 (from result above)
$copydir = findmedirectory

$complete_dest = $dest & $user & $copydir (i.e. 
\\fileserver\newprofiledirectory\user1\findmedirectory )
`
```

There are clearly other files in both locations underneath user1, user2 and user3.

So far I have:
`get-childitem "\\fileserver\profiles" -filter "findmedirectory" -force -recurse | where-object {$_.PSIsContainer} | select-object fullname`

this works ^^.

When I try pipe it to grab the string of "username" i.e. user1. It starts to fall apart:

`$files = Get-ChildItem "\\fileserver\profiles" -Filter "*findmedirectory*" -force -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | select-object fullname

foreach ($file in $files)
{ get-item $files.fullname).parent.name
}`

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$specialdirectory = "xyz"
$Destination = "zyx"

$1 = "\\fileserver\profiles\" | Get-ChildItem
$User = $1.Name | where {$_ -Match "User"}
$User | foreach {
$check = test-path -pathtype Any "\\fileserver\profiles\$_\appdata\$Specialdirectory"
If ($check -eq $true) {Copy-Item \\fileserver\profiles\$_\appdata\$specialdirectory -Destination C:\$Destination -Recurse}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, something like this should work:

```
$oldprofiles = '\\fileserver\profiles'
$newprofiles = '\\fileserver\newprofilesdirectory'

Get-ChildItem $oldprofiles -Filter "*findmedirectory*" -Recurse -Force | ? {
  $_.PSIsContainer
} | % {
  Copy-Item $_.FullName (Join-Path $newprofile $_.Parent.Name) -Recurse -Force
}
```